# Return only one row from the right-most table for every row in the left-most table

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I have two tables. I want to join them in a way that only one record in the right table is returned for each record in the left most table. I've included an example below. I'd like to avoid subqueries and temporary tables as the actual data is about 4M rows. I also don't care which record in the rightmost table is matched, as long as one or none is matched. Thanks!

table users:

```
-------------
| id | name |
-------------
| 1  | mike |
| 2  | john |
| 3  | bill |
-------------
```

table transactions:

```
---------------
| uid | spent | 
---------------
| 1   | 5.00  |
| 1   | 5.00  |
| 2   | 5.00  |
| 3   | 5.00  |
| 3   | 10.00 |
---------------
```

expected output:

```
---------------------
| id | name | spent |
---------------------
| 1  | mike | 5.00  |
| 2  | john | 5.00  |
| 3  | bill | 5.00  |
---------------------
```

Comment: Why is everyone grouping by user.id (a primary key) and user.name? After you group by a primary key, you really don't need anything else. Am I missing something, or are we all just copying @OMG Ponies?

Comment: @TheJacobTaylor: Standard SQL requires that you include columns not wrapped in aggregates in the GROUP BY.  The ANSI standard does support not defining all the columns if there's unnecessary subgrouping involved - MySQL supports this, but it won't work on most other databases.

Comment: @TheJacobTaylor: MySQL doesn't require all the grouping columns; almost every other DBMS does, and so does the SQL standard.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! That was one of those things that I tend to try to run, read the error, slap forehead, tweak query, and run again.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT u.id,
         u.name,
         MIN(t.spent) AS spent
    FROM USERS u
    JOIN TRANSACTIONS t ON t.uid = u.id
GROUP BY u.id, u.name
```

Mind that this will only return users who have at least one TRANSACTIONS record.  If you want to see users who don't have supporting records as well as those who do - use:

```
   SELECT u.id,
          u.name,
          COALESCE(MIN(t.spent), 0) AS spent
     FROM USERS u
LEFT JOIN TRANSACTIONS t ON t.uid = u.id
 GROUP BY u.id, u.name
```

Comment: Ah! Of course. Sometimes I get so myopic. One question aside, wasn't there a JOIN in earlier versions of MySQL that naturally did this?

Comment: Yes, it is called a left join. :) Right join will force a match. Left joins will include matches but not require them.

Comment: @Mike Sherov: ANSI-92 has a NATURAL JOIN, supported by [MySQL since 3.23](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/join.html), but it's just an inner join.  I don't know how early you're thinking...

Comment: I don't think `COALESCE(MIN(t.spent), 0)` is necessary here. The `LEFT JOIN` is doing the work to "see users who don't have supporting records as well as those who do". All COALESCE would do here would be to replace NULL values with a value of 0, which might or might not be helpful, depending on the purpose of the query.

Comment: The MIN() aggregation approach also works on text fields, at least on postgres.

Answer (score 6):

If you do not care about the particular row that you get back.

```
select id, name, spent
from users
left join transactions on users.id = transactions.uid
group by id
```

This will return one row per user. It will be the first matched transaction.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies if this doesn't actually answer your question.  It looks like you are trying to see which users have at least one transaction.  You could do this and in the process see how much each user has spent by doing something like this:

```
SELECT 
    u.id,
    u.name,
    SUM(t.spent) AS total
FROM 
    USERS u
    INNER JOIN TRANSACTIONS t 
        ON t.uid = u.id
GROUP BY 
    u.id
    , u.name
```

Comment: They specifically state in the question one or no matches are both fine.