# MYSQL JOIN with incrementing id

Tags: php, mysql, join

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL JOIN query help: return only one row from the right-most table for every row in the left-most table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313614/mysql-join-query-help-return-only-one-row-from-the-right-most-table-for-every-r)

To clearify and hopefully help myself:

```
table1
------------
ID | jobname
_____________
1  | job1
2  | job2
3  | job3

table 2
-------------
ID  | jnid | image#
1   | 1    | 1.jpg
2   | 1    | 2.jpg
3   | 2    | 3.jpg
4   | 2    | 4.jpg
5   | 1    | 5.jpg
```

Output desired:
job1 - 1.jpg
job2 - 3.jpg
etc till I run out of jobname (right now 17 entries) each job could have 5+ images. I want to randomly select an image from image# that correspondes to jobname up to the total amount of jobname without duplicating an image or jobname. 17 jobnames and 17 random images that link to that job.

Comment: The mysql extension is now deprecated. Please don't use it for new code. Use PDO or Mysqli instead. Also, what is your criteria for selecting the single photo per job? First / last by Id?

Comment: can you add sample records with desired result?

Comment: `GROUP BY photo_ptitle.id` ? :)

Comment: @Tomasz Should work but I hate how MySQL lets you use `GROUP BY` without any aggregate functions

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.jnid GROUP BY t1.ID
```