# Sql return one row from right table every left table result

Tags: mysql, sql, join

My question is how do I get 1 result from each result from Table1 for Table2? And not al results also from table2? I already searches stack overflow I found how to solve this with a id but I want to know how to do this with a Varchar column.

Table1

```
+--------------+-------------+
| Ip (Varchar) | Count (Int) |
+--------------+-------------+
| 1.1.1.1      | 9           |
| 1.1.1.2      | 6           |
| 1.1.1.3      | 1           |
+--------------+-------------+
```

Table2

```
+-------------+--------------+
| Name (Text) | Ip (Varchar) |
+-------------+--------------+
| User01      | 1.1.1.1      |
| User034     | 1.1.1.1      |
| User012     | 1.1.1.1      |
| User21      | 1.1.1.2      |
| User24      | 1.1.1.2      |
| User3       | 1.1.1.3      |
+-------------+--------------+
```

Wanted result

```
+--------+---------+-------+
| Name   | Ip      | Count |
+--------+---------+-------+
| User01 | 1.1.1.1 | 9     |
| User21 | 1.1.1.2 | 6     |
| User3  | 1.1.1.3 | 1     |
+--------+---------+-------+
```

It does not matter what name will be returned.

Comment: How do you decide which result(s) to return?

Comment: It looks like you want to join tables 1 and 2 on the IP, which is easy enough for us to help you with, but how do you choose which `name` to keep?

Comment: It does not matter what name .

Comment: So do you need *any* name, or can it be omitted?

Comment: I only need 1 random name each ip.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL JOIN query help: return only one row from the right-most table for every row in the left-most table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313614/mysql-join-query-help-return-only-one-row-from-the-right-most-table-for-every-r)

Comment: I didn't know that a varchar column also can be grouped on alfabetic wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you just need a random name, you can use `group by` since you're using `mysql`:

```
select t1.ip, t1.count, t2.name
from table1 t1 
    join table2 t2 on t1.ip = t2.ip
group by t1.ip
```

Depending on your data, you may need an `outer join` as well.

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a45f2/1)

Answer (score 1):

You should start by joining the two tables together on the condition that the ip address matches:

```
SELECT t2.name, t2.ip, t1.count
FROM firstTable t1
JOIN secondTable t2 ON t1.ip = t2.ip;
```

However, this will return all rows in the second table with a matching ip, so results will appear more than once. If you only want to see specific pairings, you should group by the ip column:

```
SELECT t2.name, t2.ip, t1.count
FROM firstTable t1
JOIN secondTable t2 ON t2.ip = t1.ip
GROUP BY ip;
```

As far as the `name` goes, if you're not picky you can leave it as above and it will be picked arbitrarily, or you could chose something consistent like the minimum username:

```
SELECT MIN(t2.name), t2.ip, t1.count
FROM firstTable t1
JOIN secondTable t2 ON t2.ip = t1.ip
GROUP BY ip;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e75b/3) example. It shows all three queries so you can visualize the steps I took.